# Setting value to microcontroller over serial

Tags: c++, c, microcontroller, nucleo

I'm currently working on a project. I'm sending UDP messages from a program on the computer, to a raspberry PI who has a nuclear F303RE microcontroller connected via serial. 
The microcontroller has one sensor and one led connected. If the sensor voltage drop under a specific value, the led will lighted up. 
From my program, I send a UDP message to the raspberry PI, who forwards it to the serial port and the microcontroller.  Setting the trigger value ***"d"*** in the program only works one time. After setting it for the first time, it won't let me set it again. I've been searching around for a day now, but haven't found any solution. Anyone here have an idea ?

```
#include "mbed.h" 
DigitalOut Vcc(PA_0);
AnalogIn aInnA1(PA_1);
DigitalOut Gnd(PA_4);
DigitalOut myled(PA_6);

static float voltage1=0.0f;


void utspenning() 
{
float voltage1 = aInnA1*3.3f;  
printf("$VOLTAGE,A1,%.2f\r\n" ); // This sends value back to the program
}

int main()
{
Vcc=1; Gnd=0;
char e [9];

while(1)
 {   
 scanf("%[^\r\n]s",e); // Reads my input from the program
 float d = atof(e);

    if (voltage1 > d ) 
        {
                    myled = 1;
        }
    if (voltage1 < d ) //  
             {
                myled = 1;
                wait(0.1);
                myled = 0;
                wait(0.1); 
            }
}}
```

Comment: In your function `void utspenning()`, you are declaring  `voltage1` again. Hence in that function, you are using it as local variable. Value won't be updated in `static float voltage1`. Also, When are you calling `utspenning() `??

Comment: The scanf format specifier is suspicious.  Perhaps you want `"%8s"` or `"%[^\r\n]"`, but I don't believe the 's' should appear after the ']'.  The call to printf also seems wrong.  You specify a float to be printed but you don't provide the value of the float in a subsequent argument.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger?  What happens?

Comment: It works fine in the debugger. The program let me set the d value once.

Answer (score -1):

I"m not familiar with this micro or the environment you're developing in but I suspect voltage1 needs to be declared volatile.

Comment: Only hardware registers need `volatile`, for example the LED. Presumably `DigitalOut` includes `volatile` semantics.